# django proxy: how to handle the nested src js, css?

Tags: python, django, proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy server for my django app, I have installed the django-http-proxy.

Following the setup, I have

> url(r'^proxy/(?P.*)$',HttpProxy.as_view(base_url='http://www.python.org/')),

Then I tried to use http://localhost:8000/proxy/

I get the html page, but the embedded js, css in the original page cannot be found. such as:

> static/stylesheets/style.css

Of course, this file can be accessed by http://www.python.org/static/stylesheets/style.css

But is there a way to get the page correctly? Do I have to parse all the links to be absolute path?

Thanks

Comment: what is to be gained by proxying django via django? What is your objective?

Comment: @e4c5 I have two servers, I want to use my django server to proxy the pages in another server. I do not want the user to see my 2nd server. The plan is to proxy every request to server1.com/proxy/xxx/yyy to server2.com/xxx/yyy. So user won't know there's a server2

Comment: Sorry wrong approach all together. Django itself is ideally served behind something like nginx. Nginx itself has fairly decent proxy capabilities. Django can sit behind pure proxies like varnish as well. You can use them for this task with much better configuration and performance.